# How can I eliminate the duplicate queries (validation & controller) on this typical laravel 5 case?

Tags: php, database, laravel, validation, controller

I have two custom rules on a custom request file (ClientAsocCardRequest) for validation purpose

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'code'      => ['required', 'bail', 'size:20', new QRCodeAvailability()],
        'client'    => ['required', 'bail', 'integer', 'min:1', new CardAsocAleardy()],
    ];
}
```

1 QRCodeAvailability

---

```
...
public function passes ($attribute, $code) {

    $qrcod = QRcod::find($code);
...
```

2 CardAsocAleardy

---

```
...
public function passes ($attribute, $clientid) {

        $client = Client::find($clientid);
...
```

The previous code generate two queries on the database. In the controller code I have:

```
...
public function asociatecard(ClientAsocCardRequest $request) {

    $qrcode = QRcod::find($request->code);
    $client = Client::find($request->client);
...
```

Now, the previous code generate the same queries on the same request flow. So if I neeed to check the client and qrcode eloquent entities before, and also I need to work with the same entities on the controller after; how can I reduce the number of generated queries.

Comment: You can use $request and store your previous result and use in your controller.
$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option:

*Note: I can not find the exact code I wrote at the moment, but something similar to this does the job. Did not tested the code but I wrote it to give an idea.*

```
public function action(Request $request) {
    $validator = $this->getValidationFactory()->make($request->all(), [
        'id' => 'required|int'
    ]);

    if(! $entity = Model::find($request->input('id'))) {
        $validator->getMessageBag()->add('id', 'Wrong id');

        throw new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator);
    }

    // Do action on $entity.
}
```

Another option:

You can also use ValidationException statically. This way

1- You can use the `Request` class for the rest of the validation rules. (I don't like it btw since your rules fall apart.)

2- Or use `$this->validate($request, ['rules'])` instead of `getValidationFactory()` and `getMessageBag()` stuff.

```
public function action(Request $request) {
    $validator = $this->validate($request, [
        'id' => 'required|int'
    ]);

    if(! $entity = Model::find($request->input('id'))) {
        throw new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
            'id' => ['Wrong id']
        ]);
    }

    // Do action on $entity.
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I use a little variation of the first option u gave me .

Answer (score 0):

IMO there are no other way to do validation against database without doing query. If your goal is reducing query call, maybe the only way is doing it with simple `if`. By the way Laravel already provide validation rule for checking if a certain record with a field value exist in database. You may follow this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-exists). So your rules should look like:

```
return [
    'code'      => ['required', 'bail', 'size:20', 'exists:qr,id'],
    'client'    => ['required', 'bail', 'integer', 'min:1', 'exists:clients,id'],
];
```

Comment: Yea I know that man, but I need extra validation check, is not just the "find" method what I need to do in the validation method. But thanks for the answer .